# Excel VBA - Date format issue between English language version and Danish language version

Tags: excel, vba

I'm encountering a problem with date formats in a Macro enabled Excel workbook. I'm running a Danish language version of Office365.

Basically, the workbook imports a bunch of CSV files into separate sheets of the workbook. Each CSV contains accounting data containing dates in the format DDMMYYY. All dates are "casted" as.NumberFormat ="dd-mm-yyyy"

Multiple macros are run across the data in the sheets, creating a "base sheet" combining all data of interest, from where subsequent user searches are made. While doing this, strings of VBA code are added to cells in some of the sheets, combining data from the different sheets. The added code in the macros are in English language type - but these will not work from the front-end, where the GUI requires Danish language input (e.g. VLOOKUP is used in the macro while the frontend requires the Danish version LOPSLAG) (this might have smth to do with my issue)

When all macros are run and have "processed" the raw CSV files, the user has the option to search across the data limiting the output by adding the desired date in a specific field - and here is where my problem comes.

Even if I have added the "date cast", I need to make my date search in the US format MMDDYYYY.

Anyone with an idea of how to "globally" cast the dates in the desired format across the whole workbook?

Comment: after importing the CSV into Excel, what is the exact content of the cell? Is it a string that might look like a date or is it a real date? You cannot cast to a numberFormat  - a `numberFormat` just tells Excel how do *display* a date. You can display a date in different local versions, but the value of the date itself (which is in fact a number) does not change.

Comment: as excel and vba differ in working with dates, if you have your data stored on a workbook xlsx or xls... you can add a helper column and write a custom vba function or a worksheet function that will extract dates in the format you want and then process it. But make frequent chekcs in your helper column to see if you have month greater than 12 or only days less thant 20 and years in relation to the data. If dates are messed up, you may end up with years in middle age and both excel and vba will process it without any visible issues

Comment: Excel stores dates as the number of days since (usually) 1-Jan-1900.  So long as you properly import the data so that the imported dates are "**real** Excel dates" and not text strings,  macros that refer to these dates should not have a problem.  If you have properly imported the dates, the issue is in your VBA routines, and how you are trying to handle the dates.  A language specific issue in a VBA routine might arise if you are trying to set the `.NumberFormat` property of a range, or writing formulas to cells instead of doing the calculation in VBA.

Comment: If you are writing formulas to cells, you can try using the `.FormulaLocal` property`

Comment: @FunThomas - the dates are being imported properly - my "casting" is meerly a definition of the date format - not a casting from text to date. My imported data shows the right values in the desired format (DDMMYYYY) - but my search requires the US format MMDDYYYY. The issue must lie in the systerm interpretiation somewhere - and I just want to get this fixed :-)

Comment: @pascalb - I'm already extracting months and days in other columns (to deterrmine what FiscalYear a posting refers to) - whicha again adds up, that the dates in the imported sheets are valid

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I'll give the.FormulaLocal a try :-)